# kitaev-honeycomb : can't get wilson loop squared to yield +1

Tags: condensed-matter, commutator, spin-statistics

I'm new here, loving this website and I'm having some difficulty with the wilson-loop operator in kitaev's honeycomb model.

**problem statement**
The Kitaev model ([Kitaev, 2006](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0506438) is the original paper) consists of spins residing at the lattice sites of a honeycomb lattice with separate nn couplings for the three directions that are identified for the bonds. 
The wilson-loop operator is $w_p=\sigma^x_1 \sigma^y_2 \sigma^z_3 \sigma^x_4 \sigma^y_5 \sigma^z_6$, where the indices $i \in\{1,...,6\} $ indicate the $6$ lattice sites involved in the hexagonal loop (see picture).

[image: Kitaev honeycomb loop]

In Jiannis K. Pachos' book (Introduction to topological quantum computation, 2012) the author states that $(w_p)^2=1$, which I'm trying to find myself. Actually this should be not at all hard, but I'm stuck unfortunately.

**attempt at solution** I've tried the following
$$
(w_p)^2 = \sigma^x_1 \sigma^y_2 \sigma^z_3 \sigma^x_4 \sigma^y_5 \sigma^z_6 \sigma^x_1 \sigma^y_2 \sigma^z_3 \sigma^x_4 \sigma^y_5 \sigma^z_6 \\
= -\sigma^x_1 \sigma^x_1 \sigma^y_2 \sigma^z_3 \sigma^x_4 \sigma^y_5 \sigma^z_6 \sigma^y_2 \sigma^z_3 \sigma^x_4 \sigma^y_5 \sigma^z_6 \\
= -\sigma^y_2 \sigma^y_2 \sigma^z_3 \sigma^x_4 \sigma^y_5 \sigma^z_6 \sigma^z_3 \sigma^x_4 \sigma^y_5 \sigma^z_6 \\
= + \sigma^z_3 \sigma^z_3 \sigma^x_4 \sigma^y_5 \sigma^z_6 \sigma^x_4 \sigma^y_5 \sigma^z_6 \\
= + \sigma^x_4 \sigma^x_4 \sigma^y_5 \sigma^z_6 \sigma^y_5 \sigma^z_6 \\
= - \sigma^y_5 \sigma^y_5 \sigma^z_6 \sigma^z_6 \\
=-1
$$

Where I've pulled $\sigma_1$ through first, next the $\sigma_2$, etc.
And I've used $\{\sigma^\alpha_i , \sigma^\beta_j \}= 2 \delta_{i,j}\delta_{\alpha,\beta} I_2 $ (so that every swapping of unequal $\sigma$'s gives a minus sign and $\sigma^\alpha_i\sigma^\alpha_i =I_2$ ).

So I get $(w_p)^2=-1$, which is not what I wanted to find. All text on the subject state that $w_p$ acting on a lattice configuration yield $w_p=\pm1 $ which can be easily concluded from $(w_p)^2=1$ (the expression I didn't get).

My guess is that my commutation relations are not correct, but I'm unsure. Who can help me out? A big thanks in advance!

Best,
L

Comment: $w_p$ is a tensorial product (the site indices are different), not a simple product.

Comment: From your formulas, $\omega_p^2=(-1)^{5+4+3+2+1}=-1$. I wonder whether there is an $i$ missing in your definition of $\omega_p$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have in the commutation relations, $\sigma_i \sigma_j= \sigma_j\sigma_i$ e.g. spin operators on different sites commute, so there is no minus sign to pick up.

Comment: Thanks! Fundamental things like this are what I often forget.

Comment: Is it true? Don't spin-operators on different sites *anti*-commute? $\{\sigma^\alpha_i,\sigma^\beta_j\}=\delta_{ij}\delta_{\alpha\beta}$. For distinct sites $\alpha\neq\beta$, $\{\sigma^\alpha_i,\sigma^\beta_j\}=0$. The spin operators anti-commute.

Comment: The spin operators anti-commute on the same site, but commute if they're on different sites. If found a quite useful book [here](http://books.google.nl/books?id=gayEZZo8yRIC&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=do%20spin%20operators%20on%20different%20sites%20commute?&source=bl&ots=lmSPL0PPUG&sig=Nn2Ft2XrrjvHaK78iw8525B_98E&hl=nl&sa=X&ei=U0AIVMyUI4mqO7_LgdgB&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=do%20spin%20operators%20on%20different%20sites%20commute%3F&f=false) that treats the fact.